# Geometric Progressions: Finding the number of terms that will double the first term

Tags: sequences-and-series

If the value of an article is assumed to increase annually by 5% of its value at the beginning of the year, after how many years will its value double.

Here is what I've done so far:
Value at beginning of year = x, number of years = n, r = 1.05 
x[1.05^(n-1)] = 2x

How do I solve for n?

Comment: This means that $(1.05)^{n-1} = 2$. Have you learnt about logarithms yet?

Comment: It is  $1.05^n$.

Comment: If the word "logarithm" does not ring any bells to you, the only way to solve it is trial and error. On a pocket calculator (the kind that might be solar powered), type `1.5` and hit the multiply button twice. Then see how many times you need to press the $=$-button to get past $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Your progress so far is correct. $x1.05^{n-1} = 2x$ implies that (dividing by $x$ on both sides):
$$1.05^{n-1} = 2$$

Taking the **logarithm** of both sides yields:

$$(n-1)\log(1.05) = \log(2)$$

Can you take it from here?